# Is it possible to edit the RSS Viewer in SharePoint 2007 using a Content Editor Web Part?

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2007

I need to make my RSS Viewer scroll vertically and I have the Javascript code working.  I tried editing the .xsl in the RSS Viewer but it would not scroll.  Is there a way to link the two web parts so I can edit the RSS Viewer using the Content Editor Web Part or is there a way to import the RSS data into the Content Editor Web Part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.
What you may try is using SharePoint Designer and the DataView webpart, using an XML data source. But at the end of the day, it's very similar to the RSS webpart.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and if it doesn't work, I guess I won't use the scrolling reader.